# Pivot and Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, odata

This question is all around the same topic but 2 scenarios.

I have a set of values that I am pulling from OData. It has a column that has Variables in that I want to pivot and join together

```
    create table xmpltbl
(   [Location]  nvarchar(max),
    [Site]      nvarchar(max),  
    [Variable]  nvarchar(max),  
    [Period]        datetimeoffset(3),  
    [StringValue]   nvarchar(max),
    [NumericValue] decimal(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO xmpltbl
(
    [Location],     
    [Site], 
    [Variable], 
    [Period],   
    [StringValue],
    [NumericValue]
)

VALUES 

('UK','London','Customer1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Company A',NULL),
('UK','London','Product1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897', 'Sand' ,NULL),
('UK','London','Division1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Supplies',NULL),
('UK','London','Expense1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,150),
('UK','London','Customer2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','CompanyB',NULL),
('UK','London','Product2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Bricks',NULL),
('UK','London','Division2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Building Materials',NULL),
('UK','London','Expense2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,300),
('France','Paris','Customer3','2020-01-01 00:28:53.897','Company C',NULL),
('France','Paris','Product3','2020-01-01 00:28:53.897','Cement',NULL),
('France','Paris','Division3','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Supplies',NULL),
('France','Paris','Expense3','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,75);
```

I need Variables with the same numbers to be on the same row with value next to them. Ideally I would like to do this with SSIS as I am pulling the data using that.

I want it to look like this

```
Location    Site        Period      Customer    Product     Division        Total
UK       London     2019        CompanyA    Sand        Supplies        150
UK       London     2019        CompanyB    Bricks      Building Materials  300
France      Paris       2020        CompanyC    Cement      Supplies        75
```

There is also some data that doesn't correspond with

```
Customer1 + Product1, Division1, Expense1
```

and needs to be

```
Customer1 + Product10, Division10, Expense10

Customer1 + Product11, Division11, Expense11
```

I thought about using a dynamic pivot as there are about 60 of these variables which I got to work. However it's the join but I can't do. 
I tried to do a CROSS APPLY but it won't give me the value back even if I put it into a temp table.

```
DECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
         @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Variable) 
            FROM xmpltbl
            GROUP BY Variable
            ORDER BY Variable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Location, Site, NumericValue, Period, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Location
                    , Site
                    , Variable
                    , NumericValue
                    , Period
                    , StringValue


                from xmpltbl
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(StringValue)
                for Variable in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute (@query);
```

Comment: "However it's the join but I can't do."    What join?   There is only one table in your question.    Please show us your dynamic pivot query and what is wrong with the results.

Comment: yes there is one table, perhaps should have used the word selected rather than joined. So it ends up like the above    Customer1 + Product1, Division1, Expense1

Comment: In that case I don't understand exactly what it is you can and cannot do.  Again it would be clear if you would post your code, and what was wrong with the results.

Comment: I edited the post and put my dynamic query. There is nothing wrong with the query I just don't know how to get the results into 

**Location Site Period Customer Product Division Total**

Comment: I think that using sub-queries or CTE is easier than using dynamic pivot, you got a good answer on that. have you tried it??

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if this is the best way to do this using SQL, but the following solution gives the expected result:*

### Importing to temp table

I used the following query to import data into a temp table:

```
create table #xmpltbl
(   [Location]  nvarchar(max),
    [Site]      nvarchar(max),  
    [Variable]  nvarchar(max),  
    [Period]        datetimeoffset(3),  
    [StringValue]   nvarchar(max),
    [NumericValue] decimal(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO #xmpltbl
(
    [Location],     
    [Site], 
    [Variable], 
    [Period],   
    [StringValue],
    [NumericValue]
)

VALUES 

('UK','London','Customer1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Company A',NULL),
('UK','London','Product1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897', 'Sand' ,NULL),
('UK','London','Division1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Supplies',NULL),
('UK','London','Expense1','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,150),
('UK','London','Customer2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','CompanyB',NULL),
('UK','London','Product2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Bricks',NULL),
('UK','London','Division2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Building Materials',NULL),
('UK','London','Expense2','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,300),
('France','Paris','Customer3','2020-01-01 00:28:53.897','Company C',NULL),
('France','Paris','Product3','2020-01-01 00:28:53.897','Cement',NULL),
('France','Paris','Division3','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897','Supplies',NULL),
('France','Paris','Expense3','2019-01-01 00:28:53.897',NULL,75);
```

### Using Common table expressions to get the desired output

I used common table expressions (CTE) in order to build the query:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Location],     
               [Site] ) - 1) / 4 as grpno FROM #xmpltbl), 
     CTE_2 AS (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grpno ORDER BY grpno) rn 
               FROM CTE_1),
     CTE_3 AS (SELECT *, case when rn = 2 Then 1 else 0 end as Product, case when rn = 3 Then 1 else 0 end as Supplies
               FROM CTE_2)
SELECT DISTINCT [Location], [Site], Year([Period]) as [Period], 
                FIRST_VALUE(StringValue) OVER(PARTITION BY grpno ORDER BY rn) as [Customer] ,
                FIRST_VALUE(StringValue) OVER(PARTITION BY grpno ORDER BY Product DESC) as [Product] ,
                FIRST_VALUE(StringValue) OVER(PARTITION BY grpno ORDER BY Supplies DESC) as [Supplies] ,
                MAX([NumericValue]) OVER(PARTITION BY grpno) as [Total] 
from CTE_3
```

### Output

[image]

---

*Side note: This solution works only in SQL Server 2012 or higher versions since it utilizes from `FIRST_VALUE()` window function [which is added in SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)*